# React / PrimeReact app not rendering datatable content from web service using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, web-services, primereact

Beware, I'm all new to ReactJS and PrimeReact. I'm trying to build a page that shows a list of persons, data drawn from another, Java backend server.

First off, here's the JSON data:

[image]

Here's my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PersonManager from './PersonManager';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<PersonManager />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As you can see, I'm calling `PersonManager.js` to display the actual content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';

import 'primereact/resources/themes/nova/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';

class PersonManager extends Component
{
    _entities = []

    get entities()
    {
        return this._entities;
    }

    set entities(entities)
    {
        this._entities = entities;
    }

    setEntities(entities)
    {
        this._entities = entities;
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/bbstats/ws/person/findall';
        
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
            {
                // this._entities = data;
                // this.setEntities(data);
                this.setEntities(data);
                console.log('This is your data', data);
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div style={{ maxWidth: 1440, marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto" }}>
                <DataTable value={this._entities}>
                    <Column field='id' header='ID' />
                    <Column field='lastName' header='Last Name' />
                    <Column field='firstName' header='First Name' />
                    <Column field='incognito' header='Incognito' />
                </DataTable>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default PersonManager;
```

However, the PrimeReact datatable stays empty.

In my browser (FF) it looks like the following:

[image]

I'm all new to this ReactJS / PrimeReact stuff and I have no idea why this doesn't display correctly.

I tried the same with data constructed in the component itself, which shows multiple rows (see sources below).

**QUESTION**:

What am I doing wrong?

Note, that the console correctly prints the data fetched from the other server. ‍♂️

Comment: The way you set up your class makes sense, but it's more of a java way to do things than a react way (in this instance at least). I recommend you to instead add `entities` to the state and update this state with `this.setState` (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class). If you pass part of the state and the state is changed your component will rerender and reflect the changes to your state.

Comment: Hmm. I tried using the state var before, but this didn't have any effect. I will retry and maybe update the code example.

Comment: I changed the code to the above. Still no datatable rows displayed. Please confirm if this is the React-ish way to do things.

Comment: I haven't tried your code out yet, but one problem with this is that you're still passing `this._entities`. Instead you should pass `this.state.entities`.

Comment: So true. You are my hero for this weekend. It works now. React is still a little creepy to me. Please post something as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Rolled back for good. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class PersonManager extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {entities: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/bbstats/ws/person/findall';

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({entities: data});
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{maxWidth: 1440, marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto'}}>
        <DataTable value={this.state.entities}>
          <Column field="id" header="ID" />
          <Column field="lastName" header="Last Name" />
          <Column field="firstName" header="First Name" />
          <Column field="incognito" header="Incognito" />
        </DataTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonManager;
```

So we can save `entities` in the state of the `PersonManager` component with an initial value. Since the constructor runs before the component mounts and renders we can safely access `this.state.entities` inside `render`.

In class-based components we can then update parts of the state (`entities` in this case) with a `this.setState` call which re-renders the component. This way the component correctly reflects the current state of the component.